# Garbage collector not able to reclaim memory resources

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, blockingcollection

I am trying to test how the heavy objects are handled inside the .net `BlockingCollection`.

I am getting the heavy objects using some API, and want to process it in multiple thread. In order to do that, I have one thread that reads the heavy objects and push them into multiple threads where each thread has its own blocking collection and each of those thread takes the object out of the collection and process. I am expecting that when the object is removed from all the collection wherever it is sitting, GC should be able to clean it up. That clean up is not happening and my program is going out of memory.

Calling `GC.Collect()` in between is helping me to complete the process but it has significant performance hit which I cannot afford to take.

My only question is why Garbage Collector is not able to free up the resources here even if the objects are out of scope.

```
public class DummyProcessor
{
    List<BlockingCollection<object>> listOfBlockingCollection = null;

    void ProcessCollection(object blockingCollection)
    {
        BlockingCollection<object> collection = (BlockingCollection<object>)blockingCollection;

        while (collection.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            object heavyObject = collection.Take();

            CallExternalProcess(heavyObject);
        }
    }

    private void CallExternalProcess(object heavyObject)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Analyze(object heavyObject)
    {
        if (listOfBlockingCollection == null)
        {
            listOfBlockingCollection = new List<BlockingCollection<object>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                BlockingCollection<object> coll = new BlockingCollection<object>();

                listOfBlockingCollection.Add(coll);

                Thread pt = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessCollection));

                pt.Start(coll);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            listOfBlockingCollection[i].Add(heavyObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said `GC.Collect()` makes it work, that means the garbage collector can collect the items, it is just choosing not to. Have you tried running a memory profiler on the program up to the point it crashes with a out of memory error? Perhaps the objects are not out of scope when you think they are, you add the same object to all 25 collections, if one of the threads is running slow all objects it still needs to process can't be collected. I still am curious why you use 25 collections causing the same object to be processed 25 times.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Visual studio memory profiler is running terribly slow, probably I will need to let it run overnight. But I am sure that those objects are not being released even after they are removed from all the collection. The code I provided is the the overview of whats happening in original code. Same object is being added to multiple collection because each collection is processed in its own way and written to different datastore in their own format.

Comment: I have been a major fan of [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), it comes with Resharper if you have it, or it also has a free 5 day trial if you don't.

Comment: Use the debugger to see if the queues still hold a refrence. ConcurrentQueue has a case where it does not null out an item that was taken (`if (this.m_source.m_numSnapshotTakers <= 0) this.m_array[low] = default(T);` no idea what this means).

Comment: @usr there are windows when people are viewing a snapshot of the queue in time, for example during a enumeration of its `GetEnumerator()` call. During that time it does not null out the items. If a item was dequed during that window the only way it gets dereferenced is when the Segment it was in is dereferenced by being completely dequeued and not in any running enumerators. Segments are 32 elements in size.

Comment: @usr however, if the `ConcurrentQuese`'s are not used anywhere besides in the code the OP showed, doing a `BlockingCollection.Add` or a `BlockingCollection.Take` won't cause `m_numSnapshotTakers` to be incremented ever so objects will always be nulled out.

Comment: How do your code got the heavy object? Are you sure that the reference for it is only in this code?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks. I am going to try dotmemory to figure out whats going on.

Comment: @VMAtm I am sure that the reference of Heavy object is not there in any other place. otherwise explicit call to GC.Collect would not collect them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 25 is the number of different processes heavyobject has to go through. Each process has its own BlockingCollection. My only concern is why GC is not reclaiming the resources when heavyobject is taken out and processed from 25 blockingcollection but explicit call to GC.Collect is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the application through dotMemory, I found that the heavy objects were being produced too fast that they were getting accumulated into various `BlockingCollection` in large number beyond the computer memory.
My explicit call to `GC.Collect` was working not because it was releasing the used heavy object but it was adding kind of pause to heavy object production giving more time to consumer threads to clear what is already in the `BlockingCollection`.
So I had to introduce wait between the heavy object producer and consumer so that I don't overuse available memory. For that I am using the `AutoResetEvent`. I am calling `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne` after the collection size reaches some range and as soon as it comes below the range I am calling `AutoResetEvent.Set` to run the producer again.

Thank you everyone for your input on this.

Answer (score 2):

Right now I can't see any threats in this code, if the `Analyze` is being called in thread-safe manner. If there is some analysis from the dotMemory, please add it to the question.

However, I want to point out the way you are calling the `Analyze` method. First of all, you initialise `listOfBlockingCollection` variable in non-thread safe way, because if you have a two threads running the `Analyze` method, you can get the race **and** a situation in which more than one thread runs the `if` clause in your code.

In this case, you are creating minimum 25 ghost threads, and, more significant, you can get the situation then your `listOfBlockingCollection` have **more than 25** items: if some thread already out of `if` clause, and other one still creates threads and adds collections to the list (you can check out the `listOfBlockingCollection.Count`, for example). One thread is at least 2 MB in memory, and, as `IDisposable` object, it's being collected not so quick as you might want.

Other problem with your code is that `25` threads is a non-efficient number of threads (only if you have a super-computer with 32 cores this could be an option) because of the context-switching. It better to use number of threads equal to the numbers of cores in your system or, which is better, switch your code to `Task`-oriented (you easily can create 25 tasks for the processing, and loop inside them).

Another option, if you need some additional data workflow, you can use a [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) library with 25 [`ActionBlocks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) in your application starting 25 different flows. After finishing the heavy object queue, you can easily [send the `Complete` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx) all accross the blocks and finish your execution.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I need to call the Analyze method in thread safe manner. However the code I pasted here is the replica of what I am doing in real project. Sorry about that.